# Loading specified number of CSV files in R

Tags: r, csv

I have 200 CSV files, and I want to load only 50 files out of it.
I had already checked this function:

```
fl <- list.files(directory, pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE)
```

On Providing Path to the directory, the above function loads all files in the directory.
Is their any alternative which help me to load specified number of files so that I can minimize the execution time of program.

Answer (score 1):

If we need to only read the first 50 files,  subset the 'fl' `vector` using `head` and then read the files in a `list` with `lapply`

```
fl1 <- head(fl,50)
lst <- lapply(fl1, read.csv, header=TRUE)
```

Comment: I misunderstood my own problem, The Actual Problem is loading the specified number of files into the memory.

Comment: @ViralParmar  By using the `list.files`, you are only getting the names of the files as a string.  I don't know if you have 1e7 files in the directory to create the kind of problem you mentioned.  Reading the specified number of files happen only in the `lapply` step.  If `read.csv` is a bit too much, `lapply(fl1, fread)` can be more efficient after loading `library(data.table)`